# Jquery: different width for child divs with same parent and child classes, based on number of child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Noob at jquery, and keep struggling with isolating divs.

Got a few parent divs with different number of child divs. Trying to set child divs width, based on number of child divs in each parent div. My script keeps counting them all, and not each parent separately.

html for it would be

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

and jquery

```
$(".parent").each(function(){  
  var prodchildren = $(".parent").children().length;
   if (prodchildren > 1) { $(".child").css('width','49%'); }
   if (prodchildren > 2) { $(".child").css('width','33%'); }
   if (prodchildren > 3) { $(".child").css('width','24.5%'); }
   if (prodchildren > 4) { $(".child").css('width','19.5%'); }
});
```

Comment: You can try first selecting all parents and then looping through them to get the count of children and setting widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your HTML and JS don't match up. Heres a way to do it in jQuery, though, and its quite simple. For the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

You can use this script:

```
$(".parent").each(function(){
    // instead of using if, why don't you just calculate it?
    // first, check the width of a child by dividing 100 by the amount of children
    var child_width = 100 / $(this).children().length;
    // then, round it to the below number so you get a nice round number and the total doesnt exceed 100 
        child_width = Math.floor(child_width);
    // the $(this) selector represents the current .parent
    $(this).children().css("width", child_width + "%");
})
```

Comment: This is perfect! in fact, this is great! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it works for you :) Please mark an answer as correct (either mine or chaed23's since he had the right solution as well)

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(this)` to get the current item in the iteration.

```
$(".basecollections").each(function(){  
  var prodchildren = $(this).children().length;
   if (prodchildren > 1) { $(".product777").css('width','49%'); }
   if (prodchildren > 2) { $(".product777").css('width','33%'); }
   if (prodchildren > 3) { $(".product777").css('width','24.5%'); }
   if (prodchildren > 4) { $(".product777").css('width','19.5%'); }
});
```

Comment: top child divs get width of bottom child divs

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that width of 100% NOT just should be devided by number of children.
Since is it possible to work with decimal numbers in percents I would calculate this all including a 0.5% margin (guess this is what whaaaaz wants to).

so style in css:

```
.parent > .child {margin-left:0.5%}
.parent > .child:last-child {margin-right:0.5%}
```

and calculate with jquery:

```
$(".parent").each(function(){
    var children = $(this).children().length;
    var child_width = ((100-0.5-(0.5*children)) / children).toFixed(3);
    $(this).children().css("width", child_width + "%");
})
```

Comment: I dont know why you use `:last-child { margin-right: 0.5; }` - I would think you would have _no_ margin on the last child, so all have a margin except that one, nicely spreading it out. In that case, `var child_width` could be `100.5 / $(this).children().length - 0.5` - which is much clearer to read.

Comment: @somethinghere: If I take a look into the code snippets from the question of whaaaaaz above, it seems that he wants margins. In my proposal every child element gets a left margin and just the last one gets a right margin too, as the total width of 100% is symmetrically used by e.g. 5 children and 6 spaces (margins) of the same size. Greez